# How do I replace one punctuation in a line in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to replace one punctuation in a line. I only found answers re replacing all punctuations. Is there any way to replace just one? For example, replace "?" with "."

Comment: Are you saying you want to replace all ```'?'``` with ```'.'```, or a specific ```'?'``` with ```'.'```?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow, you need to use the `replace` function.
Try this:

```
s = "Hello. My. Name. Is. Christine"
s1 = s.replace("." , ",")
print(s1)
```

Output:

> Hello, My, Name, Is, Christine

For more read [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/)

Answer (score 0):

The standard python replace function has the option of count

```
string.replace(oldvalue, newvalue, count)
```

So if you call

```
"asbda".replace("a","b",1)
```

result is "bsbda"